# How to plot the difference between two ggplot density distributions?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot2 to illustrate the difference between two similar density distributions. Here is a toy example of the type of data I have:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Make toy data
n_sp  <- 100000
n_dup <- 50000
D <- data.frame( 
    event=c(rep("sp", n_sp), rep("dup", n_dup) ), 
    q=c(rnorm(n_sp, mean=2.0), rnorm(n_dup, mean=2.1)) 
)

# Standard density plot
ggplot( D, aes( x=q, y=..density.., col=event ) ) +
    geom_freqpoly()
```

Rather than separately plot the density for each category ( `dup` and `sp` ) as above, how could I plot a single line that shows the difference between these distributions?

In the toy example above, if I subtracted the `dup` density distribution from the `sp` density distribution, the resulting line would be above zero on the left side of the plot (since there is an abundance of smaller `sp` values) and below 0 on the right (since there is an abundance of larger `dup` values). Not that there may be a different number of observations of type `dup` and `sp`.

More generally - what is the best way to show differences between similar density distributions?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a way to do this within ggplot, but frequently it's easiest to do the calculations beforehand. In this case, call `density` on each subset of `q` over the same range, then subtract the y values. Using dplyr (translate to base R or data.table if you wish),

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

D %>% group_by(event) %>% 
    # calculate densities for each group over same range; store in list column
    summarise(d = list(density(q, from = min(.$q), to = max(.$q)))) %>% 
    # make a new data.frame from two density objects
    do(data.frame(x = .$d[[1]]$x,    # grab one set of x values (which are the same)
                  y = .$d[[1]]$y - .$d[[2]]$y)) %>%    # and subtract the y values
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +    # now plot
    geom_line()
```

[image: plot of subtracted densities]