# How to overlay several plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot in one graph 3 different occupancy patterns: a.) when both male and female are working; b.) only male working; c.) only female working.

I created 3 different data.frames using `facet`

The structure of the first data.frame (both male and female is working) is:

```
   structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00", 
"05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45", 
"07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", 
"08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", 
"10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15"), day = c("Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Shifts on Monday", "Shifts on Tuesday", 
"Shifts on Wednesday", "Shifts on Thursday", "Shifts on Friday", 
"Shifts on Saturday", "Shifts on Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(102, 110, 116, 120, 148, 152, 188, 204, 318, 348, 
    418, 442, 752, 816, 1064, 1144, 1836, 1942, 2402, 2524, 3240, 
    3324, 3486, 3520, 3594, 3592, 3596, 3568, 3594, 3626), size_f = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Sunday"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The structure of the second data.frame (male is working) is:

```
dput(head(melted_WkSTiWeekM , 30))
structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00", 
"05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45", 
"07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", 
"08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", 
"10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15"), day = c("Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Shifts on Monday", "Shifts on Tuesday", 
"Shifts on Wednesday", "Shifts on Thursday", "Shifts on Friday", 
"Shifts on Saturday", "Shifts on Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(56, 58, 64, 68, 84, 84, 104, 114, 172, 196, 224, 
    238, 410, 442, 560, 604, 930, 968, 1188, 1230, 1576, 1620, 
    1692, 1706, 1740, 1746, 1752, 1740, 1736, 1756), size_f = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Sunday"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The structure of the second data.frame (female is working) is:

```
structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00", 
"05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45", 
"07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", 
"08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", 
"10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15"), day = c("Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Shifts on Monday", "Shifts on Tuesday", 
"Shifts on Wednesday", "Shifts on Thursday", "Shifts on Friday", 
"Shifts on Saturday", "Shifts on Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(46, 52, 52, 52, 64, 68, 84, 90, 146, 152, 194, 
    204, 342, 374, 504, 540, 906, 974, 1214, 1294, 1664, 1704, 
    1794, 1814, 1854, 1846, 1844, 1828, 1858, 1870), size_f = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Sunday"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

After this I created a

```
melted_WkSTiWeekAll=cbind(melted_WkSTiWeek,melted_WkSTiWeekM,melted_WkSTiWeekF)



structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00"
), day = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Shifts on Monday", 
    "Shifts on Tuesday", "Shifts on Wednesday", "Shifts on Thursday", 
    "Shifts on Friday", "Shifts on Saturday", "Shifts on Sunday"
    ), class = "factor"), value = c(102, 110, 116, 120, 148), 
    size_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Sunday"), class = "factor"), time = c("04:00", "04:15", 
    "04:30", "04:45", "05:00"), day = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
    "Monday", "Monday"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Shifts on Monday", "Shifts on Tuesday", 
    "Shifts on Wednesday", "Shifts on Thursday", "Shifts on Friday", 
    "Shifts on Saturday", "Shifts on Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(56, 58, 64, 68, 84), size_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00"), day = c("Monday", 
    "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Shifts on Monday", "Shifts on Tuesday", 
    "Shifts on Wednesday", "Shifts on Thursday", "Shifts on Friday", 
    "Shifts on Saturday", "Shifts on Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(46, 52, 52, 52, 64), size_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The variable `time, day, variable and size_f` are similar.

I would like to plot 3 graph together in the same plot. But I have no clue how to this

Using the suggested `facet` the following plot

Plot1

[image]

Plot2

[image]

Plot3

[image]

How to move forward

I would like to create a pot like this

[image: Lesnard]

Comment: lookup gridExtra or ggplot facet

Comment: Maybe you can try `ridgeline` or `joy` plots

Comment: @qwr I managed to create individual graphs how to overlay the plot?

Comment: @CPak thanks any examples please

Comment: @M-M thanks , any suggestion how to continue, I am working on this idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066444/how-to-plot-the-difference-between-two-density-distributions?rq=1

Comment: @user11418708 do you want to combine all the facets (all days of weeks) into one plot overlaying each other or have different plot for each day but combine your 3 different plots and have 3 densities on each facet?

Comment: @ M-M thanks for your reply; i don't want densities - but I want the plot to be similar to the densities -> basically I just want to overlay all 3 plots to show their intersection -> to show the daily working aptterns of males and females

Comment: ```library(tidyverse);
melted_WkSTiWeekAll <- bind_rows(list(All=melted_WkSTiWeek,Male=melted_WkSTiWeekM,Female=melted_WkSTiWeekF), .id = 'source');
ggplot(melted_WkSTiWeekAll ,aes(x=time,y=value,fill=source)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha=.3, width=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~day)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by merging your dataframes together and tag them as `All`, `Male`, and `Female` accordingly. Then you can use that tag for grouping(coloring) within your `ggplot` function.

Using `geom_bar` and `position = "identity"` you will get bars on top of each other and to remove the space between the bars (to mimic density plots look) `width` is set to `1`. `alpha` can be used to alter the transparency of `fill` colors.

And to get a separate plot for each day of the week we can use `facet_wrap(~day)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

melted_WkSTiWeekAll <- bind_rows(list(All=melted_WkSTiWeek,
                                      Male=melted_WkSTiWeekM,
                                      Female=melted_WkSTiWeekF), 
                                                                .id = 'source')

ggplot(melted_WkSTiWeekAll, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=source)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity", alpha=.3, width=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

<sup>Note that here we only get one `facet` as the data provided only has entries for Monday.</sup>
[image]
<sup>Created on 2019-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>